# Rsyslog filtering messages based on time

Tags: syslog

I want to filter logs so that only messages from 13:00-14:00 can go through, how can I do that? I know I can access message content with `$msg`, but how can I do that for time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the hour part of the timestamp using a regular expression `[0-9]{2}:`, but capture just the 2 digits by using `()` namely `([0-9]{2}):`.

```
if re_extract($timestamp,"([0-9]{2}):",0,1,"xx")=="13" then /my/file
```

See [RainerScript](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/index.html)